# Boot into nvme not supported by motherboard

Tags: server, grub2, live-usb, bootloader, nvme

I have a Dell PowerEdge 730.

I installed ubuntu to its M2 drive using a live cd usb.

But it doesn't boot to M2 since the motherboard doesn't detect it. Neither the bios nor grub seem to detect the M2 drive.

Is there any way I can boot into it without attaching a new hard drive? Like installing grub on a usb stick?

Comment: What is your motherboard's CPU and chipset?

Comment: Its a dell poweredge 730